# Writing a AWK script by taking the input file as an argument

Tags: linux, awk, scripting

I'm new to Linux, so this might be a relatively simple task but my research failed me. 
I want to write a **awk script** where it should iterate through a input file which has only one word per line and assign it to a variable, and I have to do some string operations on it. 
I'm quite confused with how to take the word on each line (by referencing the input file entered in the terminal) and assign it to a variable.

Comment: Did you already read the awk manual?

Comment: This question would be much improved with examples of 1) the file you intend to parse, 2) what you're hoping the output will be like and 3) a sample of what you've already tried so far.

Comment: What be the variable(s) that you want to assign to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If each line has a single word on it, `awk` would put that word in `$1` ("the first field").  You can then extract it from there and put it in a variable if you like, with `var = $1`.  Regardless, you can do any string operation that you wish by operating on `$1` (or `var`, if you assigned the value to that variable).

For example, assuming each word looks like `word=otherthing` and we'd like to output only `otherthing`:

```
awk '{ split($1, a, "="); print a[2] }' infile
```

or shorter,

```
awk -F '=' '{ print $2 }' infile
```

`$2` is the second field on each line, and with `-F '='` we tell `awk` that the fields are delimited by `=`.

You don't mention what it is you need to do, so I won't give more examples.

You may also write this as a script that a user can call directly:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { FS = "=" }

{ print $2 }
```

This would be saved in a text file, made executable (with `chmod +x script.awk`), and then a user could call it with

```
./script.awk infile
```

... assuming the `#!`-line pointed to your `awk` binary.

Comment: Thank You. The Script file worked for me. But I assigned like this var=$1.

Comment: how do you specify the infile inside the script file itself?

Comment: @ychaouche By taking the first or second command in this answer and making that into a shell script (which just means adding `#!/bin/sh` as the first line and making the file executable).

Comment: thanks @Kusalananda. I out there's another solution where you set ARGV[1] and ARGC to 2 inside the BEGIN block. [Source](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/how-to-read-a-file-inside-awk-874908/#post4327324)

Comment: @ychaouche If that works for you, then go with that. It's an unusual and awkward way to misuse the internal command line argument variables, and I would never suggest writing code like that.